# Excel VBA Script to Copy and Paste Data from a Predefined List of URLs

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm pulling my hair out over this. I've seen other topics that almost address this question, but their methods are normally too specific. I don't need anything as complicated as scraping

I have about 64,000 URLs in column A of my file. I want Excel to go to each URL and once it loads, copy the entire page and then paste it into Excel. I would like all the pasted data in the same workbook and same sheet pasted one after the other.

Comment: Please read this before you ask any more questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  We are not going to write your code for you.  You need to show us what you have tried, tell us what *specifically* is not working, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: *I don't need anything as complicated as scraping* - do you really understand what scraping is and how it works? You are asking exactly for that. However, there is one alternative that may help. see `Data > From Web` in the Excel Ribbon. Use macro recorder to get started with the code, if you don't know the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's the finished code, if anyone was wondering.

```
    Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
Dim Erw, Frw, Lrw
Drw = 1
Frw = 1
Lrw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Erw = Frw To Lrw

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;" & Range("A" & Erw).Value, Destination:=Range("G" & Drw))
        .Name = ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "6"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Drw = Drw + 80
Next Erw

End Sub
```